# nginx server fails to show images

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

My problem is that I am running on linux, an nginx server. The problem comes when I upload a spleen and when I download it, the images come from the location /uploads. What I have a problem with is that it tries and retrieves the images from the Documents/uploads folder not the Documents/projectname/uploads folder. How can I write this to handle that?

I downloaded the image on the backend and want to send it back to the frontend.
e.g.: /uploads/carousel/image.png or /uploads/aboutus/image2.png etc.. etc..

```
server {
listen 80;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
root /usr/share/nginx/projectname;
server_name projectname;

location /uploads {
root /home/pi/Documents/projectname;
client_max_body_size 5M;
set $proxy IP;
proxy_pass http://$proxy;
}

location /api {
client_max_body_size 5M;
set $proxy IP;
proxy_pass http://$proxy;
}
```

Comment: Post the nginx error message.

Comment: No error message. :/

Comment: There is no error message in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`? then from where do you know nginx tries to load the files from `/home/pi/Documents/uploads`? Also, please use absolute paths in your question to prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: I know because that's where the pictures come from. That's where they load from. And since that's where the pictures are, I guess that's where it's taking the pictures from. However, how exactly I can get it to take the files from the exact location is a good question. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved if i delete proxy_pass.